# Tern Fails to use JSDoc Type Information

Tags: javascript, parsing, type-inference, jsdoc, tern

I'm trying to use [Tern](http://ternjs.net/) to perform type inference on some Javascript code. However, the type inference doesn't seem to be using the JSDoc comments alongside the code.

I'm using the code `/** @type {Foo} */ let x;` as an example of the problem. On the [Tern website's demo page](http://ternjs.net/doc/demo/#simple) (which uses CodeMirror), the editor is able to infer that the type of `x` is `Foo`.

Yet, when run locally via node, I get this back: `{ type: '?', exprName: 'x' }`.

Here's a snippet that replicates the issue:

```
const tern = require('tern');

const ternServer = new tern.Server({
    plugins: {
        doc_comment: {
            strong: true
        }
    }
});

const js = `/** @type {Foo} */ let x;`;
ternServer.addFile("main", js);
ternServer.request({
    query: {
        type: "type",
        file: "main",
        start: js.length - 2,
        end: js.length - 2
    }
}, console.log);
```

Tern has otherwise been working perfectly fine for type inference. It's when using the JSDoc comments that it doesn't seem to work with the way I've initialized and called it.

I even set the [`doc_comment`](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#plugin_doc_comment) plugin to `strong`, which means that JSDoc types are preferred over normally inferred types, but to no avail.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you have to import the `doc_comment` plugin in order to use it. Otherwise, setting the plugins option for the tern server won't do anything.

Simply adding `require("tern/plugin/doc_comment");` to the top of the file solved the problem.